# How to find hyperlinks in Excel 2010 and de-activate them?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, find, hyperlink, deactivation

When opening my Excel sheet using Excel 2010, I get a yellow bar at the top from Excel informing me that it has de-activated the automatic update of hyperlinks.

To my best knowledge, I do not know that I ever entered a hyperlink.
I have even copy-pasted the content to a new sheet some time back, with no success.

How do I find these hyperlinks, so that I can delete them?

Answer (score 3):

You can deactivate the links through Office button and the Excel options button, see [Turn off hyperlinks](http://blogs.mccombs.utexas.edu/the-most/2010/09/24/turn-off-auto-hyperlinking-in-excel-2007/).

Hyperlinks can be found through the search function, see [Finding Excel hyperlinks](http://excelhints.com/2010/05/26/find-and-delete-external-links/). Quoting from the source:

> **Using the Find Feature**
>
> A quick way to cycle through your external
>   links (depending on the number you have) is to use the find feature
>   built into Excel.  We will be searching for “[“, left bracket, which
>   can help identity those external workbook references.
>
> - Hit Ctrl+F (or Edit–>Find on your toolbar) on your keyboard to open your find wizard
> - Click the “Options” button to open additional criteria
> - Select: within “Workbook”
> - Select: look in “Formulas”
> - Finally, enter a left bracket “[” in the Find What field (without double quotes)
>
> That’s it.  Excel will now go through and show you all the instances
>   where the left bracket has been used in your spreadsheet, which should
>   identify external references to other spreadsheets.
>
> **Delete Links Add-In**
>
> Microsoft has also provided an add-in to help you
>   identify and delete links.  To view Microsoft’s solution to this
>   problem, visit http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=188449. 
>   There is an additional Read-me file to help you use the add-in after
>   you extract from the exe file.

The reason the Find Feature works is that external references are identified by a set of brackets. However, the feature also finds whatever left brackets you might have on the document, not just the ones corresponding to external references.